# Possible to Run Wordpress Query on MySQL Query (maybe during)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a custom table within the wordpress database that contains a record of posts that a logged in user has "liked." Now I need to display these posts, but I'm trying to figure out how I can loop through the posts that only they have liked.

My MySQL query that brings in their "liked" posts looks like this, but I'm stuck at how I can access the php variable $current_post_in_mysql_loop during the MySQL query so that I can output it using a WP_Query:

```
SELECT * FROM gw_activities
  WHERE 'activity_post_id' = $activity_post_id
  AND 'wp_user_id' = $wp_user_id;
```

My Wordpress Query would be something like this:

```
<?php
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'gw_activity', //CPT being queried           
  'p' => $current_post_in_mysql_loop, // Post ID
  );


$my_query = null; 
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  <?php endwhile; }
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to do the second WP query for your objective?  If you already have the post ids from your first query, can't you foreach loop over that and use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post in order to get your posts?

Comment: It looks like I might be trying to over complicate things. I'll take a swing at your suggestion. Thank you